# Model not Binding to Action passing Null as value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know why, the Model is not binding to the Create Action:

ViewModel:

```
public class AddressContactViewModel
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources), Name = "AddressContactViewModelNameLabel")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMsgRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources))]
    public int ContactType_Id { get; set; }

    public int Address_Id { get; set; }

    // ViewModel dropdownlists
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContactTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.AddressContactViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address_Id)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>AddressContactViewModel</legend>

       <div id="year">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ContactType_Id)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactType_Id, Model.ContactTypeList, HeelpResources.AddressContactViewModelContactTypesListDropDownFirstRecord)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactType_Id)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Contact)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Contact)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Action Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult ContactCreate(AddressContactViewModel contact)
    {
        var contactDto = Mapper.Map<AddressContactViewModel, AddressContactDto>(contact);

        _addressContactService.Create(contactDto);

        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Address.ContactList());
    }
```

**EDIT:** Get:

```
    public virtual ActionResult ContactCreate(int addressId)
    {
        var model = new AddressContactViewModel
            {
                Address_Id = addressId,
                ContactTypeList = ContactTypeDropDownList()
            };

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I submit the Form, I receive "null" in the contact parameter of the ContactCreate action, why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Weird, all looks okay, when you debug your action method what's in the `Request.Form` collection?

Comment: Can you post your HttpGet action?

Comment: Have you tried using @Html.EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor. I try and only use TextBoxFor When I need to specifiy lengths

Comment: ? Request.Form
{__RequestVerificationToken=84iJz1X3gzFzrgFBUM5E7t5_UawDyjjlgp3D-NC64iUdVHm0XfXr242adDwBuJu5Kp91Ffv-RRZtpCre89AMD_xZaoC7YQbKuJdpboAQs_Ai4IkjalB_fKLYLdmXsZMO0&Address_Id=1041&ContactType_Id=3&Contact=965420760}
    [System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: ........

Comment: Hi, I ad the form to create the view and the result of the Request.Form

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` line in your view?

Comment: Thanks but I found the problem, published below

Answer (score 3):

Unbelievable, I found the problem, the parameter of the action has the same name of a field in the ViewModel, a change of the parameter name and everything works find:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult ContactCreate(AddressContactViewModel addressContact) // HERE I CHANGE FROM contact TO addressContact AND THE PROBLEM GET SOLVED
    {
        var contactDto = Mapper.Map<AddressContactViewModel, AddressContactDto>(addressContact);

        _addressContactService.Create(contactDto);

        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Address.ContactList(addressContact.Address_Id));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem on my last app. try encompassing the button and the field you want to submit into the same div:

```
@model Heelp.ViewModels.AddressContactViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address_Id)

<fieldset>
    <legend>AddressContactViewModel</legend>

   <div id="year">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ContactType_Id)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactType_Id, Model.ContactTypeList, HeelpResources.AddressContactViewModelContactTypesListDropDownFirstRecord)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactType_Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Contact)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Contact)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Is your Address_Id property null when the model is passed back to the controller?

Comment: Hi, the contact parameter is null in the post back and the request.from is Request.Form
{__RequestVerificationToken=n8AM-8LxejrP394kQSs9hKHvrVCjRO2mhK1ZKg3oQNj-zfS3rLLyuQ83HIqqpI-OWZqdiedjQcSVzfes-PQTK7LB6vqmyW97wI6uAubbN-XeDgbrPeMF4CBhq7STNRu00&Address_Id=1041&ContactType_Id=3&Contact=965420760} as you can see Address_Id has value 1041